# What does "in kind" mean in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-meaning

Excerpted from [bigthink.com](http://bigthink.com/think-tank/is-incest-wrong):

> Secondly, people claim that incest creates ‘deformed’ children. This is not entirely true. There is a greater risk of various handicaps, true, due to a closer sharing of genetics. But there is a danger in every form of child creation that the child might be handicapped. There might be a difference in degree of risk in incestuous sex acts but certainly not **in kind**.

What does *in kind* mean in this paragraph?

I found two meanings in an online dictionary:

1. If you do something in kind, you do the same thing to someone that they have just done to you.
2. (of ​payment) given in the ​form of ​goods or ​services and not ​money.

but neither make sense to me in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, these two prepositional phrases parallel each other:

> There might be a difference **in degree of risk** in incestuous sex acts *compared with other sex acts*, but certainly not **in the kind of risk**.

Both incestuous and non-incestuous sex carry a risk of detrimental mutations. The risk is of the **same kind**. But incestuous sex, when it results in conception, carries a **higher risk** of detrimental mutations in the newborn. Thus, the **degree of risk** is different for incestuous sex compared with non-incestuous sex.

---

The author tries to counter this argument:

> incest creates ‘deformed’ children.

First off, he says "this is not entirely true". Then he explains his position in more detail by saying that all kinds of sex carry some risks, but that does not make these kinds of sex radically different (different **in kind**).

---

> 30% vodka and 40% vodka both consist of grain alcohol mixed with water. There might be a difference **in degree** of alcohol between them, but certainly not **in kind**.

---

In a more sober vein, a **[quote](http://www.thegreatideas.org/apd-man.html)** from Adler's Philosophical Dictionary:

> Two entities differ *in degree* if both have the same defining traits, but one has more and one has less of the same trait.

Comment: So "certainly not in kind" is just the repetition of "There might be a difference in degree of risk in incestuous sex acts compared with other sex acts"?

Comment: @CYC Incestuious sex acts and other sex acts are **different in degree** as concerns the risk of resulting bad mutations. But they are **not different in kind**. The risk is of the same kind, only it's higher for incestuous sex acts.

Comment: @CYC Maybe I failed to explain it clearly. Feel free to wait before accepting the answer, it's the usual practice. (0: I googled for examples but found mostly trainloads of philosophical treaties on degree/kind, not a simple read really.

Comment: Is "There might be a difference in degree ...  but certainly not in kind." some kind of refute to "But there is a danger in every form of child creation that the child might be handicapped."? Meaning the author imagined that someone who disagree with incest might using "Though they all have risks, they are still not the same"  statements to refute "all kind of sex have risks". (Of course the author then refute this argument back in the end of the paragraph)

Comment: @CYC - No, this is a refute to "*incest creates ‘deformed’ children*". The author agrees that incestual conception carries the risk of mutations. Then he says: "but that risk of mutations exists in other kinds of sex too". So we have a difference in degree, not in kind. This makes consensual incest between adults more acceptable, in the author's view.

Comment: So "not in kind" means "not different in kind, unlike the difference in risk degree"="they are the same kind" in this context. (But if there is no any syntaxes or sentences to compare, just the phrase "not in kind" solely,  it might means"not in the same kind")?

Comment: @CYC - yes, it means "*the risks are of the same kind*". Had there been no sentences/phrases to compare, I would've been at a loss what to think. There is the sense "paid in kind" (in the form of goods), but that sense would demand a totally different context.